Does a given ROC curve represent a family of classifiers with the same form but with different "model parameters" other than threshold parameter?
Is the following correct?
A given ROC curve is for a family of a probabilistic classifiers under
different threshold values. As the threshold value changes, the model
parameters change as well and hence different points on ROC curve represents a family
of classifiers with different mathematical parameters (model parameters) other than threshold parameter.


No, the model parameters are fixed. The ROC curve only considers varying the classification threshold for the fixed model.
